# Is the vector produced by the difference of $x-\bar{x}I$ orthogonal to $x$?

Tags: vector-spaces, orthogonality

If I have a vector $x$ in N dimensions and I compute $y=x-\bar{x}I$ where:

- $\bar{x}=\frac{\sum_{i}^{N}x_i}{N}$
- $I$ is a vector of lenght N where each position is equal to $1$

Is the vector $y$ orthogonal to $x$? If yes, can you prove it formally?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

You have to check if $y\cdot x=0$ (dot product).

$$y\cdot x=x\cdot x-\bar{x}(x\cdot I)$$
$$y\cdot x=|x|^2-\bar{x}(x\cdot I)$$

Is $|x|^2=\bar{x}(x\cdot I)$?

See that,

$$x\cdot I=\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_i,$$ and

$$|x|^2=\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_i^2.$$

Can you finish?